# How to determine number of occurences of a subtext in a text in Excel?

Tags: excel

As mentioned above, I would like to ask for help in writing a formula in Excel that would allow me to count all the specific String occurrences in a bigger String.

Let me show You exactly what do I mean by that:

[image: [Excel sheet]

I have a rather small database of products (around 150 different items), but their names are generally similar and because of that some words may repeat often and may be misleading when treated one-by-one.

I tried to fix the issue with MATCH and INDEX functions, but to be honest didn't really get the gist of them ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(F2,CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),A:A,0)))
```

Depending on ones version this is an array formula and may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: This is great, but for me it returns only one value: #101. Also had to modify , with ; since for my Excel version ; is the delimiter.

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: Yes I did, it added curly braces to the whole formula.

Comment: Then I do not know why, can you show me the actual formula you used.  Do not translate it, just the full formula as is.

Comment: =POŁĄCZ.TEKSTY(" ";;INDEKS(B:B;PODAJ.POZYCJĘ(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&PODSTAW(F2;ZNAK(10);"</b><b>")&"</b></a>";"//b");A:A;0)))

Which is exactly Yours formula translated by: https://pl.excel-translator.de/translator/

Comment: FILTERXML step outputs only "B T", I suppose this is the moment in which it crashes since it should return a list, am I correct? Or not?

Comment: It outputs an array, select four cells in one column and put just the FILTERXML part in the formula bar and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  It should put the four items in one per cell.

Comment: Ah, yes, now indeed it works :) So the product was correct, I just didn't provide enoguh output cells. Thank You very much! :)